# Java Fill JLabel with Background Color over time

Tags: java, swing

Is there any way to fill a JLabel slowly over time with a background color from left to right?

I am trying to set up some kind of audioplayer.

The text which is spoken is shown(written) in a JLabel and I would like to have some kind of "animation" when the File with the spoken text is being played.
Some kind of bar going from left to right through the JLabel would work as well.

I appreciate any kind of help/ideas.

Thank you!

Comment: Please, provide a code snippet to help us help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

We can help with if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: john25 you can use JProgress bar not a JLabel.Calculate a time of you spoken audia an set it to Jprogressbar

Comment: Thanks Mahesh24, but I already tried it and I wasn't very happy with the look of it. Also I need to do some other stuff with the JLabel(s) and I am not sure if I can handle everything with a JProgressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filling it I would either create another JPanel or JLabel within your JLabel, that has whatever background color you want, and then just changes its size over time.
That will give you the same effect.

Another, though more complicated way, is to hide another JLabel to the left of your statusbar, and then move it to the right so it slowly appears. Definitely not the fine way to do it though.

If you use JavaFX, you can find a progress bar there which will be the probably perfect way to program your statusbar, but probably the most complicated as well if you are not using it right now.

Comment: Thank you, the JLabel within the JLabel idea sounds great. I will definitely try it as soon as I get home!

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it requires you to use timer, which i don't know how familiar you are with it.

But below is an application that fills a component(JPanel) slowly with color showing progress

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Olubori
 */
public class MusicBar extends JFrame{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    JPanel [] lab;
    Timer tim;
    public MusicBar()
    {
        JPanel pan = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        lab = new JPanel[20];

        for(int i = 0; i<lab.length; i++)
        {
            lab[i] = new JPanel();
            lab[i].setBackground(Color.red);
            pan.add(lab[i]);
        }



        tim = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {


            int i = 0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               lab[i].setBackground(Color.blue);
               i++;
               if(i==lab.length)
                   tim.stop();
            }
        });

        tim.start();

        this.add(pan);


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        MusicBar mb = new MusicBar();

        mb.setSize(500, 500);
        mb.setVisible(true);
         mb.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


}
```

To use this with your application you might need to get the time duration of the file to play convert it to second and divide it by the amount of panels which here it is 20, then multiply it by 1000 to get your timers delay.

**Run the code first, then modify it to suit your application.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mock label that actually is a JPanel that contains an array of JLabels, one for each letter in the label's text.

The ProgressLabel controls the "animation" logic. The caller just stops and starts it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProgressLabelDemo implements Runnable
{  
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new ProgressLabelDemo());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    final ProgressLabel progressLabel =
        new ProgressLabel("Testing", 500, Color.YELLOW);

    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
        progressLabel.start();
      }
    });

    JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
    btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
        progressLabel.reset();
      }
    });

    JPanel pnlButtons = new JPanel();
    pnlButtons.add(btnStart);
    pnlButtons.add(btnReset);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Progress Label Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(progressLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(pnlButtons,    BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setSize(300,  100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public class ProgressLabel extends JPanel
  {
    private JLabel[] labels;
    private Timer timer;
    private int labelIndex = 0;

    public ProgressLabel(String text, int delay, final Color progressColor)
    {
      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

      int size = text.length();
      labels = new JLabel[size];

      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        String s = String.valueOf(text.charAt(i));
        labels[i] = new JLabel(s);
        labels[i].setOpaque(true);
        add(labels[i]);
      }

      timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener()
      {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
          showProgress(progressColor);
        }
      });
    }

    private void showProgress(Color bgColor)
    {
      if (labelIndex < labels.length)
      {
        labels[labelIndex].setBackground(bgColor);
        labels[labelIndex].revalidate();
        labels[labelIndex].repaint();
        labelIndex++;
      }
      else
      {
        timer.stop();
      }
    }

    public void start()
    {
      timer.start();
    }

    public void reset()
    {
      timer.stop();
      labelIndex = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
      {
        labels[i].setBackground(new JLabel().getBackground());
      }
    }
  }
}
```